# Can't close mysql connections in R

Tags: r, rmysql

Would appreciate any tips regarding how to close MySQL connections in R.

Used `dbDisconnect()`, but it kept throwing an error:

> *Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function 'dbDisconnect' for signature
>   '"MySQLConnection"*

Answer (score 0):

In order to disconnect you need to give `dbDisconnect()` the right connection.
Make sure your connection does have a name in the first place. Always open a connection with

```
mydb <- dbConnect(..)
```

As soon as you don't need it anymore you can close it with

```
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```