# Unable to close RMySQL connection by dbDisconnect command

Tags: r, rmysql

Tried to close connection using the name of the db by subsetting the output, as in:

```
  con<-dbListConnections(MySQL())
```

And here is the command that generates an error.

```
 dbDisconnect(con[1])
```

I keep getting the same error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbDisconnect’ for signature ‘"list"’

I searched on SO, but didn't find a solution to eliminate this error. All I got was various ways of closing the db connections using a for loop or lapply.

We have same question asked a while back on SO but no answer.
[Can't close mysql connections in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363887/cant-close-mysql-connections-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Got the error.

The dbDisconnect command returns a list; not a char vector.

By subsetting to the element of the connection list I could successfully close the connection.

```
> dbDisconnect(con[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```